# Why is my IDE looking in the wrong dependency folder for a needed class?

Tags: java, android, selenium, appium

I'm trying to run a script that was working fine until I changed the home folder.
Once I changed the home folder I ran into a few issues but I was able to resolve them. The only thing I have not been able to resolve is the following error.

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/remote/internal/JsonToWebElementConverter
    at BrowserStackAndroid.main(BrowserStackAndroid.java:43)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.JsonToWebElementConverter
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 1 more
```

This is an interesting error that, after some research, I have not been able to wrap my head around.

The class that it is searching for is in the org.selenium.remote dependency. Except that it's not in the internal folder but the remote folder.
So the class that it is searching for is JsonToWebElementConverter.

This class is located in the following path
org/openqa/selenium/remote/JsonToWebElementConverter

The folder that the IDE (or Maven?) is looking into is 
org/openqa/selenium/remote/internal 
Which only has the class WebElementToJsonConverter

I've tried reinstalling the library via maven in several different ways, using different dependencies, etc but haven't been able to fix this issue.

I've never come across an issue like this before so I'm really excited to see what the solution is going to be.

Notes:
The error is being thrown because of the following line of code

```
AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver = new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>(new URL("https://" + userName + ":" + accessKey + "@hub-cloud.browserstack.com/wd/hub"), caps);
```

This project worked perfectly fine before but as soon I changed the directory of the project stopped working.

Comment: You are using maven or plain java project

Comment: Maven @Muzzamil

Comment: This problem is related to classpath as you hv changed the directory. Cab you set above mentioned selenium jar in classpath? Check here to set class path https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html and it should be added in **target/classes**

Comment: Other way is remove selenium dependencies as appium java-client already comes with selenium dependencies. It can solve your issue.

Comment: @Muzzamil I removed all the selenium dependencies and it resolved the issue. Thank you. Could you submit that as the answer and also submit the class path solution with a more detailed way of how to do it?

Comment: I have added it as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening as  you have same class or library with in 2 dependencies. Simply removing `selenium` based dependencies will resolve the issue as all `selenium dependencies` already comes with `Appium java client`. For `classpath` you can check  at [java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html)

So the way to set class path via cmd (Navigate to project root folder)

```
set CLASSPATH= target/org/openqa/selenium/remote/internal/JsonToWebElementConverter
```

**Note:** for `maven project` all compiled java files should be in `target` folder. If you are facing same issue you can add missing class in`classpath` destination should be `target` folder as explained in java docs